# How to rewrite subquery in ORDER BY clause in JPA CriteriaQuery

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I'm trying to write an SQL query using CriteriaQuery, but I'm having a hard time doing so. This query basically gets a list of shipments and sorts them by their authorization date. This authorization date is represented as the date attribute of the first record in the status transition messages table with an initial status of 3 and a final status of 4. This is my query:

```sql
SELECT s.id
FROM shipment s
ORDER BY (SELECT min(stm.date)
          FROM status_transition_message stm
          WHERE stm.initial_status = 1 AND stm.final_status = 3 AND stm.shipment_id = s.id) desc;
```

I've tried multiple different solutions, but none have worked so far.

My current iteration is as follows:

```java
private void sortByAuthDate(Root<ShipmentTbl> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder, ListSort sort) {
        Subquery<Timestamp> authDateQuery = query.subquery(Timestamp.class);
        Root<StatusTransitionMessageTbl> stmRoot = authDateQuery.from(StatusTransitionMessageTbl.class);

        Predicate shipmentId = builder.equal(stmRoot.<ShipmentTbl>get("shipment").<String>get("id"), root.<String>get("id"));
        Predicate initialStatus = builder.equal(stmRoot.<Integer>get("initialStatus"), 3);
        Predicate finalStatus = builder.equal(stmRoot.<Integer>get("finalStatus"), 4);

        // returns the authorization date for each queried shipment
        authDateQuery.select(builder.least(stmRoot.<Timestamp>get("date")))
                .where(builder.and(shipmentId, initialStatus, finalStatus));

        Expression<Timestamp> authDate = authDateQuery.getSelection();
        Order o = sort.getSortDirection() == ListSort.SortDirection.ASC ? builder.asc(authDate) : builder.desc(authDate);

        query.multiselect(authDate).orderBy(o);
    }
```

The problem with this solution is that the SQL query generated by the CriteriaQuery does not support subqueries in the ORDER BY clause, causing a parsing exception.

Comment: Why do you have to rewrite this SQL query to JPQL / Criteria Query? Can't you just continue using SQL, given that it works much more easily?

Comment: Because our current platform is already using CriteriaQuery for setting filters on the database queries, as well as for doing the actual queries to the database, so it's essential to also implement the sorting using CriteriaQuery

Comment: If you absolutely *have to* do that, you could still use views in the database. Criteria Query wouldn't notice. But I would sincerely reconsider using the relatively limited API for *everything*. There are options, you know :) Imagine calculating a running total with this API...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My CriteriaQuery-fu is not good enough to help you with that part, but you could rewrite your SQL query to this:

```
SELECT s.id
FROM shipment s
LEFT JOIN status_transition_message stm 
ON stm.initial_status = 1 AND stm.final_status = 3 AND stm.shipment_id = s.id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY min(stm.date) DESC;
```

To me, this quite likely seems to be a faster solution anyway than running a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause, especially on RDBMS with less sophisticated optimisers.

Comment: yep, thought of that as well, but CriteriaQuery / JPQL also does not support subqueries on JOIN clauses. It only supports them in the WHERE clause, nowhere else :/

Comment: @TiagoSilva: I explicitly didn't join a derived table but used `GROUP BY` instead

Comment: Yeah, I think your solution may work. Check my new question edit

Comment: @TiagoSilva: Great! You know you can add your own answer here on Stack Overflow instead of editing your question. It will be easier for future readers to understand the flow of the question.

Comment: I did that now. Do you have any ideas to solve the problem I'm still having?

Comment: Yeah, you're not ordering by `date` (which is an alias for `min(stm.date)`), you're ordering by `stm.date`. Subtle difference, in SQL :) I'll rewrite my SQL to make it more clear.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is that CriteriaQuery doesn't keep the aliased column in the SELECT statement. It just uses ```min(stm.date)``` on its own. I fixed the problem by just removing the DISTINCT keyword from the query, and it's now working perfectly!

Comment: @TiagoSilva: Very cool! Would be great to see that solution in your updated answer...

Comment: There's not anything to add though xD the problem was caused by a DISTINCT statement that isn't present in my code snippet. And it wasn't exactly a solution, as more of a workaround by removing it

Answer (score 0):

So I attempted to follow @Lukas Eder solution and reached this solution:

```java
private void sortByAuthDate(Root<ShipmentTbl> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder, ShipmentListSort sort) {
        Join<ShipmentTbl, StatusTransitionMessageTbl> shipmentStatuses = root.join("shipmentStatus", JoinType.LEFT);

        Predicate initialStatus = builder.equal(shipmentStatuses.<Integer>get("initialStatus"), 1);
        Predicate finalStatus = builder.equal(shipmentStatuses.<Integer>get("finalStatus"), 3);

        Expression<Timestamp> authDate = builder.least(shipmentStatuses.<Timestamp>get("date"));
        Order o = sort.getSortDirection() == ShipmentListSort.SortDirection.ASC ? builder.asc(authDate) : builder.desc(authDate);

        shipmentStatuses.on(builder.and(initialStatus, finalStatus));

        query.multiselect(authDate).groupBy(root.<String>get("id")).orderBy(o);
    }
}
```

But now it's throwing this exception:

```java
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
```

This happens because the query is only going to get distinct shipments later on and it's asking for the sorting column also appear in the select. The problem is I don't know how to force CriteriaQuery to keep that column in the SELECT statement. It automatically only puts in the ORDER BY.

Here's the JPQL query it's executing in my test:

```sql
select
        distinct generatedAlias0 
    from
        ShipmentTbl as generatedAlias0 
    left join
        generatedAlias0.shipmentStatus as generatedAlias1 with ( generatedAlias1.initialStatus=:param0 ) 
        and (
            generatedAlias1.finalStatus=:param1 
        ) 
    where
        lower(generatedAlias0.shipmentName) like :param2 
    group by
        generatedAlias0.id 
    order by
        min(generatedAlias1.date) desc
```

and the generated SQL query:

```sql
select
            distinct shipmenttb0_.id as id1_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.archived_date as archived2_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.auth_code as auth_cod3_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.authorization_date as authoriz4_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.booked_in_by_user as booked_i5_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.business_channel as business6_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.courier as courier7_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.courier_amount as courier_8_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.courier_currency as courier_9_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.ship_to as ship_to39_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.estimated_shipment_date as estimat10_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.last_updated_date as last_up11_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.measurement_unit as measure12_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.original_submitted_date as origina13_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.packaging_type as packagi14_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.placeholder_message as placeho15_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.scheduled_period_of_day as schedul16_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.scheduled_shipment_date as schedul17_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.ship_from as ship_fr40_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.ship_origin as ship_or41_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.shipment_name as shipmen18_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.status as status19_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.submitted_date as submitt20_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.supplier_contact_email as supplie21_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.supplier_contact_name as supplie22_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.supplier_contact_phone_number as supplie23_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.supplier_email as supplie24_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.supplier_secondary_contact_email as supplie25_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.supplier_secondary_contact_name as supplie26_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.supplier_secondary_contact_phone_number as supplie27_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.tenant as tenant28_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.total_received_boxes as total_r29_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.total_units as total_u30_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.total_value as total_v31_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.total_volume as total_v32_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.total_weight as total_w33_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.tracking_number as trackin34_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.tt_note as tt_note35_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.tt_priority as tt_prio36_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.updated_by_user as updated37_13_,
            shipmenttb0_.weight_unit as weight_38_13_ 
        from
            shipment shipmenttb0_ 
        left outer join
            status_transition_message shipmentst1_ 
                on shipmenttb0_.id=shipmentst1_.shipment_id 
                and (
                    shipmentst1_.initial_status=? 
                    and shipmentst1_.final_status=?
                ) 
        where
            lower(shipmenttb0_.shipment_name) like ? 
        group by
            shipmenttb0_.id 
        order by
            min(shipmentst1_.date) desc limit ?
```